# Obtain Decimal values after Division

Tags: java, android

How can i obtain the decimal value after division ?
after doing this

`days = miliseconds/(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

suppose the value(i.e days) is 27.8351
how do i get 8351 ?
Tried

`hours = days % (int) days` thought it s doing 27.8351 / 27 
but still it returned a big Zero, havent tried converting it into string and then splitting based on DOT (.) but i dont like this way have i over looked some thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hours = (days - (int) days) * 10000
```

(to get 4 digits after decimal)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this kind of operations. The divideAndRemainder method is available.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

If you know in advance the number of decimal places, then subtract the result by the whole number and multiply it 10 to power of the number of decimal places.

Example: # of dec places is 4 and the result is 42.8798

Process:

(1) 42.8798 - 42 = 0.8798

(2) 0.8798 * (10^4) = 8978